# Is it possible to grab user's friend's photo Facebook Graph API

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

I want to know if it is possible to retrieve a user's friend's photo (not the profile photo but ones that the user is able to view) via Graph.  I know that you can retrieve photos of friends that the user has been tagged in it, but there are photos that the user can view (using normal Facebook) but not tagged on.

I know this might sound like it would be bad for security reasons.

Thanks
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the permissions?

As seen [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)...

To read the 'photo' object you need **friends_photos** permission to access friends' photos ***and*** photos in which the user's friends have been tagged

---

Just wanted to add that (to my understanding):

You can only see if the *current user* gave you the required "friends_photos" permission.

If they did give you that permission, then you should be able to get the list of photos of the current user's friends... but only of the the albums/photos with a privacy setting of:

- *Friends*
- *Friends of Friends*
- or if the current user is part of *"Specific People or Lists"*

Comment: I actually tried that and for some reason it doesn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong though.

Comment: @Aion It could also depend on the friend's custom settings of their album/photo. I tried it myself (using the API explorer), but I only had issues when the user did NOT give the "friends_photos" perm

Comment: Okay, I tried it again on the Graph API Explorer and found out that the JSON data array will return empty if the amount of photos of the friend hits a limit.  This might be the Explorer's limitation.  I'll mark your answer as correct.  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't see your comment before I added my previous.  Do you know a way to detect if the friend has given friends_photos permission? :/

Comment: Also, I think you're right on the friend allowing the friends_photos permission.  I guess there is no limitation on the Graph Explorer as I previously stated.